# How do I access (check) the element of a std::unordered_map without inserting into it?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, square-bracket

Accessing elements of a std::unordered_map using the [ ] operator inserts new elements:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> umap = {
    {"Thomas", 1},
    {"Frank", 5},
    {"Lisa", 7}
};

// umap.size() is 3
uint32_t id = umap["Lisa"];
// umap.size() is 3
id = umap["Randy"]; // key "Randy" doesn't exist
// umap.size() is 4
```

I had naively assumed the [ ] operator would behave read-only without right-hand assignment. Do I have to check via `count()` or `find()` whether a key exists, prior to accessing it, or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to check by using `find`:

```
if (umap.find("Randy") == umap.end()) // does not exist
```

Comment: Skirts my question a bit, but if that's the only way then I'll have to go with that. I had a nice one-liner that I would have preferred to keep :)

Comment: @Adrian: I really didn't think I was skirting the question. This is what you *have* to do. If you want your one-liner back, do it inside a function.

Comment: Well, I indicated that I was aware of find(), so a clear *yes* would address that better. Anyway, thanks for the fast answer, `find()` it is.

Comment: @Adrian: You did, but "yes" won't be accepted as an answer so I just fleshed it up a little. :)

Answer (score 1):

Other than `find()` or `count()`, the other alternative is the `at()` method, which throws an exception if it's not present.